# End of Stream Parsing Error

Tags: c#

```
    public static Image Crop(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height, AnchorPosition Anchor)
        {
            if (imgPhoto == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
            int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
            int sourceX = 0;
            int sourceY = 0;
            int destX = 0;
            int destY = 0;

            float nPercent = 0;
            float nPercentW = 0;
            float nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            {
                nPercent = nPercentW;
                switch (Anchor)
                {
                    case AnchorPosition.Top:
                        destY = 0;
                        break;
                    case AnchorPosition.Bottom:
                        destY = (int)(Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent));
                        break;
                    default:
                        destY = (int)((Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nPercent = nPercentH;
                switch (Anchor)
                {
                    case AnchorPosition.Left:
                        destX = 0;
                        break;
                    case AnchorPosition.Right:
                        destX = (int)(Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent));
                        break;
                    default:
                        destX = (int)((Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
                        break;
                }
            }

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

            Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
                new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            grPhoto.Dispose();
            return bmPhoto;
        }


     public byte[] ImageToByteArray(string path)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
            long sizeByte = info.Length;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int) sizeByte);
            return  data;
        }


        public byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
        {

            if (img == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, img);
            return ms.ToArray();

        }

    public Image BrowseImage(Image image)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.FileName = string.Empty;

            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.png; *.jpg;    *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image img = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                if ((img.Width < 200) || (img.Height < 200))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Minimum size is 200x200.");
                    BrowseImage(image);
                }
                else
                {
                    return img;
                }
            }
            return image;
        }


in saving image

     picItem.Image = Crop(BrowseImage(picItem.Image), 200, 200, ImageUtil.AnchorPosition.Center);



 //set Datatable row
    erow["Image"] = img.ImageToByteArray(picItem.Image);


 //Saving is ok

    //When i View
    picItem.Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])source.Image.binaryFromDB);


>Error: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed?
```

this is all the method ive use. i crop the image so that it will have a minimum size..ive tried any convertion but no help.
    i just want to save an image to database and when i view i can see the image in picture box.

@MarcGravell I found the problem. u right man.when i store the byte in datatable it stores a value System.Byte[] not the actual bytes.. when i get all the value in datatable and put it in a query "Insert into table values('System.Byte[]'). .it stores a string System.Byte" not the binary data..

Comment: What is `byteArrayIn`? How is it filled?

Comment: are you sure that the `byteArrayIn` contains all data?

Comment: byteArrayIn is it array of byte??

Comment: byteArrayIn is the binary data of image stored in database..i want to  get the data from the database and show it in a picturebox.

i use this to convert image to byte[]
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
        {

            if (img == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, img);
            return ms.ToArray();

        }

Comment: If that it a `System.Drawing.Image`, it would be a **much** better idea to use `image.Save(memoryStream, format)` and `Image.FromStream(memoryStream)`. Beyond that: what I said about checking the length when you write it, and compare it to the length when you get it back.

Comment: i tried using that also but the error it return is Parameter is not Valid

Comment: @Snippet: There is nothing specific about C#3 or 4 here. tags removed. Dont add them again, please.

Comment: Seriously: you need to tell us "yes, I've checked the contents when obtained originally, and when obtained from the db - and they [are|aren't] identical". Until that point - the database is looking the most likely problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've loaded all the data into the `MemoryStream` and rewound the stream - all good (although `new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)` would have been easier).

This leaves one simple possibility: the array truly does not contain all of the data that it should have.

Check how you got the array, and all intermediary steps. In particular, add some debug code to note the length of the array *when you write it*, and check that you got all of it. If the length is the same, check that the **contents** are identical byte-for-byte (comparing the output of `Convert.ToBase64String` is probably the most convenient way of doing that for ad-hoc usage).

If you are writing streams, check a few things:

- if using a `Stream.Read`/`Stream.Write` loop, check you are using the return value from `Read` correctly; or easier - just use `Stream.CopyTo` instead (this has a correctly-implemented `Read`/`Write` loop)
- if using `MemoryStream`, make sure you understand the difference between `ToArray` and `GetBuffer`, and the implications of each
- if you are transferring the data at any point, make sure you are treating it *as binary* at all times - never text. No `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` / `Encoding` / `GetString` / anything like that

Comment: i use this to convert the image in the binary.            
            'BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, img);
            return ms.ToArray();'

Comment: @Snippet right; and what happens to that array between that `ms.ToArray()`, and this deserialize code? does it go to a file? to a database? any other intermediate steps? or just straight from serialize to deserialize?

Comment: after serialize i store the Byte in Datatable then the data in datatable are save in a datatabase.

Comment: @Snippet then I strongly suspect something between those two points. As I've said: verify the contents at the two points. If they aren't identical, your storage code is broken.

Comment: I also suspect that the datatable has a problem when i store the data. the Datatype of my datacolumn is SqlBinary. is that correct?

Comment: @Snippet I'd probably have used `VarBinary`, but that should work I guess. How is the column at the DB defined? `image`? `varbinary(max)`? `varbinary(n)` for some `n`? `binary(n)` ?

Comment: the column in db is define as image. Marc, When i set The datatable column datatype into System.Byte[] the data store in database is always '0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D' even i use different pictures. when i use SqlBinary as datatype i get unique data. i have test my code also base on the methods i post 

' picItem.Image = ImageUtil.Crop(img.BrowseImage(picItem.Image), 200, 200, ImageUtil.AnchorPosition.Center);
  picItem2.Image =img.ByteArrayToImage(img.ImageToByteArray(picItem.Image));'

u right man,i think all my methods are ok. i think the problem is in the datatable.